# Animation, swipe image over another image

Tags: android, image, animation, android-viewpager, swipe

How can I implement swipe of one image on another likewise the attached image.

In image one can see that background image is static, and user can able to swipe another image. Its a screenshot of housing.com app.

Can anyone help me in this.
[image]
Note: tried for viewpager, jazzyviewpager, Parallex view but no success

Comment: helping you doing what ?

Comment: I need to swipe my views exactly same as in above image. tried a lot but not getting any idea how to do it now.

Comment: I would suggest you to start simple. A ViewPager with two fragments, with two different background images.

Comment: tried with viewpager, jazzyviewpager, Parallex view but no success

Comment: would you mind showing us the *no success code* ?

Comment: Sure, Here is my xml : http://pastie.org/10404841 and here is my main activity code: http://pastie.org/10404839

I want slide over of one Image over another not sliding like viewpager.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom Viewpager(jazzy viewpager library with stack effect and disable zoomout functionality inside this) to acheive this.

Comment: No can not be possible, it could be possible only using viewpager translation and clip drawable ;)

Answer (score 0):

So after so many days of search n implementations I got this exactly.

Steps to achieve:
 1. Implement Viewpager.
 2. User custom view pager with transition.
 3. The most important one, Implement clipDrawable to clip drawable on upcoming page on view pager.

Here is the Scale transformation class uses clipdrawable :
public class ScalePageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
        private static final float SCALE_FACTOR = 0.95f;

```
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;

    public ScalePageTransformer(ViewPager viewPager) {
        this.mViewPager = viewPager;
    }

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position){
        View mainLayout = page.findViewById(R.id.bg_rel);
        ClipDrawable clipDrawable = (ClipDrawable) mainLayout.getBackground();
        if (position <= 0){
            // apply zoom effect and offset translation only for pages to
            // the left
            //              final float transformValue = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1) * (1.0f - SCALE_FACTOR) + SCALE_FACTOR;
            int pageWidth = mViewPager.getWidth();
            final float translateValue = position* -pageWidth;
            //              page.setScaleX(transformValue);
            //              page.setScaleY(transformValue);
            if (translateValue > -pageWidth){
                page.setTranslationX(translateValue);
            } else {
                page.setTranslationX(0);
            }
            clipDrawable.setLevel(10000);
        } else {
            //entering view
            int level = (int) ((1 - position) * 10000);
            clipDrawable.setLevel(level);
            mainLayout.setTranslationX(-1 * position * page.getWidth());
        }
    }
}
```

rel_bg: My main layout having drawables.

Hope it helps for somebody.